# Interpolating $5$ points using a $5$th degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate a set of $5$ data points
$$(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 5), (4, 7), (5, 69)$$
using a fifth degree polynomial.

So for some $$p(x)=ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex^1+f$$ I can plug in the points given initially and find the matrix representation of the coefficients, which gives
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\\
32 & 16 & 8 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 3\\\\
243 & 81 & 27 & 9 & 3 & 1 & 5\\\\
1024 & 256 & 64 & 16 & 4 & 1 & 7\\\\
3125 & 625 & 125 & 25 & 5 & 1 & 69
\end{bmatrix}
If we rref this, we get
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac1{120} & \frac{59}{120}\\\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac18 & -\frac{39}8\\\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{17}{24} & \frac{403}{24}\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{15}8 & -\frac{185}8\\\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{137}{60} & \frac{703}{60}
\end{bmatrix}
It is an system of equations with one extra variable so there is no singular solution. I attempted to solve for $p(x)$ in terms of the remaining coefficient $f=t$, which gives me $$p(x)=\left(\frac{59}{120}-\frac{t}{120}\right)x^{5}+\left(-\frac{39}{8}+\frac{t}{8}\right)x^{4}+\left(\frac{403}{24}-\frac{17t}{24}\right)x^{3}+\left(-\frac{185}{8}+\frac{15t}{8}\right)x^{2}+\left(\frac{703}{60}-\frac{173}{60}t\right)x+t$$
From my logic, this polynomial should work for all $t$, but it only works for $t=0$ (which can be seen by plugging in one of the points given initially and then solving for $t$).

Furthermore, if I plug in $t=59$, this should return the correct fourth degree polynomial to interpolate all the points, but the desmos graph says otherwise. (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lu0rabmtoj)

What did I do wrong, or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Can you maybe share your desmos sheet? Otherwise it might be hard to reproduce your error, but i don't think there is a big issue.

Comment: @flawr added the link

Comment: Thanks, it looks good to me. Unless there is a mistake we both did not catch it seems desmos has an issue with this problem.

Comment: it seems you made a typo, see my answer.

Comment: @flawr oh bruh that is such a stupid mistake thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated it in a very naive way in python and didn't have any issue, here is a graph for $t = -5, 0, 5, 10, 59$ and it looks like the theory works out perfectly.

EDIT: In your case you flipped the digits of the linear term, it should be 137 instead of 173, see here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rjtz8x69ho

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([1,3,5,7,69])
exps = np.array([5,4,3,2,1,0])
B = np.array(Matrix(np.column_stack([a**k for k in exps]+[b])).rref()[0]).astype(float)
X = np.arange(0, 6, 0.001)
plt.plot(a, b, 'o')
for t in [-5, 0, 5, 10, 59]:
    poly = np.concatenate([np.squeeze(B[:, -1] - t*B[:, -2]), np.array([t])], axis=0)
    Y = ((X[:, None] ** exps) * poly) . sum(axis=1)
    plt.plot(X, Y, ':')
    plt.ylim([-5, 70])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this give the same general polynomial formula as mine (with the parameter t) or is it different?

Comment: Yes it does - or do you expect there to be a reason to believe it is different?

Comment: No I was just making sure lol thanks